# Find the duration of a Video file

Tags: angular, typescript

I am uploading a video file and prior to uploading I need to know the duration of the video which is to be uploaded. How can I find this information.

I am using **Angular 11.0.9**

```
async upload(event: any){
  this.currentFile  = event.target.files[0];

  // Upload Logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileTake($event)" />

<video width="400" id="video_here" controls>
  <source crossorigin />
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


on .ts file

  fileTake(event) {
    var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    document.getElementById("video_here").setAttribute("src", fileUrl);

    setTimeout(() => {
      var myvid = document.getElementById("video_here");
      console.log(myvid["duration"]);
    }, 2500);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Try These**

`getDuration(e) { let duration = e.target.duration;}`

OR

document.getElementById("yourID").duration